# What is the difference between elastic and acoustic waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics, terminology, definition, elasticity

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave), it is written that acoustic waves are elastic waves. If they are the same then why do we have two different names? Can someone please explain the difference between these two types of waves?

Answer (score 2):

*Acoustic waves* literally means *sound waves*. Obviously, not every elastic wave is a sound wave. Also, I am not sure to what extent the waves in a gas/air or liquid can be considered elastic - I would characterize them as *pressure waves*, although sound propagating in a solid (e.g., when one taps on a metal bar) is definitely an elastic wave.